# firebase one project and 2 android with apps dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Now ,
I'm facing that issue!

I have one project in firebase named like " ProjectX " and this project has 2 android apps like "App A For Client" and "App D for Provider".

now The App A Create 2 dynamic link " ONE " for Other Client App and "SECOND" for "Provider App".

in Case one The "App A For Client" open and working but in Case "SECOND" how create a dynamic link and specific it to open the "App D for Provider". ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [official Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/dynamic-links/android/create?hl=EN) you can specify packageName in AndroidParameters, ex:

```
.setAndroidParameters(
            new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.example.android")
                    .setMinimumVersion(125)
                    .build())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).